# JAIN-SIP Java SIP API

Tags: java, android, sip, jain-sip

I am using [jsip](https://java.net/projects/jsip/sources) source code in one of SIP Supported application.The source code is available at [jsip source code](https://java.net/projects/jsip/sources).I want to understand the licence agreement for this source code.Can i edit some of functionality and reuse the same source code.I want to change few of the methods and their associated logic.

Answer (score 0):

It's public domain (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain), your should be fine. Talk to a lawyer to be sure, things may vary by country.